# Why is this `flex-wrap: wrap` only working in Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

This `flex-wrap: wrap` code works in Firefox (both laptop and mobile) but not in Chrome (when the browser's resized to small) or non-Firefox mobile browsers.

In Firefox, on a large viewport (e.g., a laptop) the images (which are all `.png`) appear side by side; and on a small viewport (e.g., a mobile phone) the images stack. In Chrome (both when a laptop browser is sized to small and on a mobile), the images move closer and closer together and then overlap each other (and butt up to the right-hand side of the screen.

[Screenshot of images overlapping on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G5lm.png)

What have I done wrong?

**NB**: the `head` contains `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 6%;
  padding-right: 6%;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo_box {
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.logo_box img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 15vw;
  min-width: 150px;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 2vw;
}

.align-items_center {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery align-items_center">
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z8NxswFxbGEQSsXZrpz--9kTwUSHmdN8Oyi0b4kibJhUeAhSCBUeZzmdoSwC8DO0QjlCg=s85" alt="Alt text 1">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z8NxswFxbGEQSsXZrpz--9kTwUSHmdN8Oyi0b4kibJhUeAhSCBUeZzmdoSwC8DO0QjlCg=s85" alt="Alt text 2">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z8NxswFxbGEQSsXZrpz--9kTwUSHmdN8Oyi0b4kibJhUeAhSCBUeZzmdoSwC8DO0QjlCg=s85" alt="Alt text 3">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z8NxswFxbGEQSsXZrpz--9kTwUSHmdN8Oyi0b4kibJhUeAhSCBUeZzmdoSwC8DO0QjlCg=s85" alt="Alt text 4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an explanation, seems like Chrome hardly recalculate size of each element on resize.

a different approach, turning margins into padding and min-width on img to its container seems less buggy for chrome:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 6%;
  padding-right: 6%;
  border: solid;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo_box {
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
  align-items: baseline;/* ?? is this a flex box ?? */
  min-width: 150px;  /* added */
  padding: 2vw;  /* from img margin */
}

.logo_box img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 15vw;
  min-width: 100%;   /* fits to parent's min-width */
}

.align-items_center {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery align-items_center">
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150" alt="Alt text 1">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100" alt="Alt text 2">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" alt="Alt text 3">
    </div>
    <div class="logo_box">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250" alt="Alt text 4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `max-width: 15vw` in the `logo_box img` declaration block.

For whatever reason, the `vw` is handled differently in Chrome and Firefox.

I would suggest using a different unit of length or removing the rule.